# Let $A\subset\Bbb N$ such that for all $a\in A,b\in\Bbb N$, there exists some $c$ such that $a+bc$ is a square. What is $A\cap\{1,2,\dots,2018\}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is the first problem of a local Math Olympiad in Spain. I'll translate it, avoiding some funny definitions:

> Let $\Bbb N^*$ be the set of positive integers, and $A$ the subset of
>   numbers $a$ in $\Bbb N^*$ such that for all $b\in \Bbb N^*$ there
>   exists some $c\in\Bbb N^*$ such that $a+bc$ is a square. What is
>   $B\equiv A\cap\{1,2,\ldots,2018\}$?

I have found that suitable (that is, from $1^2$ to $44^2$) perfect squares are in $B$, but I have stumbled upon the equation

$$a\equiv m^2\pmod b$$

**My question**: is it possible for a non square number to be a square in $\Bbb Z_b$ for every positive integer $b$?

*Secondary questions*:

- Is there any simpler solution for this problem?
- Are the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Quadratic Reciprocity Theorem necessary to solve this? (I find these theorems too strong for a local Olympiad).

Comment: If $a$ is not a square then $v_p(a)=k$ is odd for some prime $p$.  Let $b=p^{k+1}$.

Comment: Ohhh, yes, I was struggling with $b=p^k$. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

If $a$ is not a square then $v_p(a)=k$ is odd for some prime $p$.  Letting $b=p^{k+1}$ we see that $v_p(a+bc)=k$ for all $c$, hence $a+bc$ can never be a square.

Comment: Wonderful answer...

Comment: Does $v_p(a)=k$ mean $p^k\parallel a$?

Comment: @RosieF  Yes. $ $